# Problems with Pinterest Button - Error The Content-Security-Policy directive 'prefetch-src' is implemented behind a flag which is currently disabled

Tags: pinterest

I am having problems with the Chrome Pinterest Button, as well as with my own Pinterest Button in a site of a client.

When you try to pin an image, that image is not loaded in the pinterest's form. Instead you receive a 404 (Not Found) error, but the image and its url is actually perfectly correct. So there is no reason for that error. Actually, after loading the image in another tab, if you click again in the pinterest button the image then appears in the Pinterest's form.

The buttons have been working with no problem until the site changed to SLL and Php 7.1, but I really think this has nothing to do with the issue.

I have found the following error in the console:

The Content-Security-Policy directive 'prefetch-src' is implemented behind a flag which is currently disabled.

Do you have any idea about how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I solved. The problem was that the image what I am referring in the data-pin-media was not included in the post, so Pinterest is not able to get it without breaking the Content-Security-Policy.

So, I added and hide the image in the post, and now everything works as expected.

At any case, I had still a problem with the descriptions in the images to pin in pinterest that were not being taken properly. I solved taking a deep look to the url string and encoding some of the characters in the text that were making to fail the url like: | by %7C, etc..

Thanks,

PS It's just me, or lately no one offer his help answering questions on stackoverflow